# Kth smallest number algorithm doing extra work?

Tags: java, algorithm

So I'm preparing for a technical interview, and one of my practice questions is the Kth smallest number.
I know that I can do a sort for O(n * log(n)) time and use a heap for O(n * log(k)).  However I also know I can partition it (similar to quicksort) for an average case of O(n).

The actual calculated average time complexity should be:

[image: \sum_{i = 0}^{log_{2}(n) - 1} \tfrac{n}{2^{i}}-1 = 2n - 2 - log_{2}(n)]

I've double checked this math using WolframAlpha, and it agrees.

So I've coded my solution, and then I calculated the actual average time complexity on random data sets.  For small values of n, it's pretty close.  For example n=5 might give me an actual of around 6.2 when I expect around 5.7.  This slightly more error is consistent.

This only gets worse as I increase the value of n.  For example, for n=5000, I get around 15,000 for my actual average time complexity, when it should be slightly less than 10,000.

So basically, my question is where are these extra iterations coming from?   Is my code wrong, or is it my math?  My code is below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Solution {
    static long tc = 0;
    
    static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }

    static int kMin(int[] arr, int k) {
        arr = arr.clone();
        int pivot = pivot(arr);
        if(pivot > k) {
            return kMin(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, pivot), k);
        } else if(pivot < k) {
            return kMin(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, pivot + 1, arr.length), k - pivot - 1);
        }
        return arr[k];
    }

    static int pivot(int[] arr) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int pivot = rand.nextInt(arr.length);
    
        swap(arr, pivot, arr.length - 1);
    
        int i = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
            tc++;
            if(arr[j] < arr[arr.length - 1]) {
                swap(arr, i, j);
                i++;
            }
        }
        swap(arr, i, arr.length - 1);
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int iterations = 10000;
        int n = 5000;
        for(int j = 0; j < iterations; j++) {
            Random rd = new Random(); 
            int[] arr = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                arr[i] = rd.nextInt();
            }
            int k = rd.nextInt(arr.length - 1);
            kMin(arr, k);
        }
        System.out.println("Actual: " + tc / (double)iterations);
        
        double expected = 2.0 * n - 2.0 - (Math.log(n) / Math.log(2));
        System.out.println("Expected: " + expected);
    }
    

}
```

Comment: As with quicksort, the running time of a quickselect implementation is data dependent.  Your calculations assume that the pivot is in fact the median value in the array. But in practice, it almost certainly is **not** the median. And just like quicksort, the worst case for quickselect is when the pivot is always either the minimum or the maximum element in the subarray. That results in worst case running time of O(n^2).

Comment: First work on actually producing the correct answer.  Then see if it still takes too long.

Comment: @user3386109, thanks for the reference. That's quite interesting. I'll study it for details. Perhaps it is obvious that I did not study computer science. Even though I've deleted my comment I suggest you leave yours for the benefit of readers who are not familiar with (or want to brush up on) quickselect.

Comment: [This wiki article explains the quickselect algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) , and lists the best, average and worst case time complexity.

Comment: @user3386109 I know. But on a large random dataset averaged over 10,000 runs, it should run near the theoretical average. And this shows because over multiple runs I get somewhat consistent results. However those consistent results are a significant amount off the theoretical average.

Comment: @Matt Timmermans It does produce the correct answer. I'm just trying to understand why the actual time complexity does not match the theoretical.

Comment: Yours is not necessarily the "theoretical average" especially if it assumes the pivot is always the median. Won't a bad pivot be more expensive than a good one is cheap, not simply averaging?

Comment: @Nathan The comment by clwhisk is correct. Let me expand on that. With an array of length 5000, you're expecting a count of 10000, but you're seeing an average of 15000, which is 50% more. But worst case is something like 25 **million**. So if there are 10000 iterations with count 10000 and one really bad iteration with count 25000000,  the average would be 12500.  In other words, you need to look at the distribution of results, not just the average result. This comes down to the difference between "median" and "average". The median time is not affected by outliers, but the average is.

Comment: @clwhisk Okay, I get it.  What I calculated is assuming it would split the array on half on average.  But it doesn't do that.  I modified my code so it would (inefficiently) find and choose the median value as the pivot just to see, and sure enough I started getting results near the expected value.  Submit an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @user3386109, it's so easy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you and others have pointed out in the comments, your calculation assumed that the array was split in half on each iteration by the random pivot, which is incorrect. This uneven splitting has a significant impact: when the element you're trying to select is the actual median, for instance, the expected size of the array after one random pivot choice is 75% of the original, since you'll always choose the larger of the two arrays.

For an accurate estimate of the expected comparisons for each value of `n` and `k`, David Eppstein published an accessible analysis [here](https://11011110.github.io/blog/2007/10/09/blum-style-analysis-of.html) and derives this formula:

> [image: eqn]

This is a very close estimate for your values, even though this assumes no duplicates in the array.

[Calculating](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B2*n*%281%2Bln%5B%28n%29%2F%28n-k%29%5D%29+%2B+2*kln%5B%28n-k%29%2Fk%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2Cn-1%7D%5D+where+n+%3D+5000) the expected number of comparisons for k from `1` to `n-1`, as you do, gives **`~7.499 * 10^7`** total comparisons when `n=5000`, or almost exactly **`15,000`** comparisons per call of Quickselect as you observed.

[image: ans]

Comment: Thank you for the math and link. This was exactly what I was looking for.